# Undefined object in Java Script Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-media-plugin

I wrote a service for playing Media on iOS and Android in Ionic framework. It use Media plugin of Cordova. I am init media object and play it with this code in Java Script,but it returns undefined object error.

```
var self  = {
'currentTrack': null,
'initPlayer': function (videoID) {
self.currentTrack = Media(IP_ADDRESS + 'stream/'+videoID);
//self.currentTrack = _track;
console.log('initd');
},
'Play': function () {
console.log(self.currentTrack);

    self.currentTrack.play();



}
};
```

And in the template I init the audioPlayer in this way:

```
<ion-content ng-init="audioPlayer.initPlayer('foo')>
```

and in a button I declare the playing function:

```
<button ng-click="audioPlayer.Play()"
```

Error:

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.currentTrack.play')
```

Comment: Do you wait to deviceReady event before you init the media variable?

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa I am using ionic.Platform.ready(function(){}); how can I wait for the device to be ready? Thanks

Comment: Mmm yes, other way is using deviceready event for cordova:   document.addEventListener("deviceready", successCallback, errorCallback);  Do you try to debug your app using break points with Chrome's inspector?

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa I am debugging my app by Safari Developer inspector. because I run the app on Simulator,And I can debug it only via Safari Simulator web page inspector.

Comment: And you can't controle the flow using break points? and then see what happens? I used to use Safari Tecnology Preview to debug my apps on iOS

Comment: @JuanFernandezSosa Thank you so much. I didn't declare 'ionic.Platform.Ready' correctly. Now It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't declare my function in `deviceready` event correctly. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing your app in browser, Cordova plugins does not work in browsers while development.
You need to build the app in order to work the plugin.
You can use the remote debugging tool to debug the ".apk" or ".ipa". 
You can get more information about remote debugging over [here](http://docs.ionic.io/tools/developer/).

Keep the following points in mind,

1. You are executing all your code on deviceready event.
2. The cordova.js file must be first js file which you are loading.

Comment: Yes I know that, I am testing on real device and simulator. Thank you

Comment: Make sure you are executing all your code in deviceready event.

Comment: Also the cordova.js file must be first js file which you are loading.

Comment: yadaev Thank you. I didn't declare my function in deviceready event correctly. It works now.